# Can't get the "Add To Cart" Working from Agile Web Development 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days now. After numerous searches, the solutions that people provided did not work. I think it's because I'm using a newer version of rails. Anyway, the problem is that I need to get the add to cart button working this is what the book taught me to do with the create method `def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)`

I keep getting this error undefined method `line_items' for #

The previous solution that I found on other forums is to add the attributes. I did all of that and even messed around with the structure of the function, but all of them return an error when I click add to cart. For the model line_item.rb I have:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :order_id, :product, :cart
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to :product
end
```

Please help! Do I need to downgrade my rails? Some people have suggested that the super params change is the reason behind this.

Comment: Try passing them as `strong parameters`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new, could you tell me where I would set that up? Thanks

Comment: Scratch that.Try changing this line `@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)` to `@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product_id => product.id)` in `line_items_controller.rb`

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: Hey, I tried that solution already, didn't work

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Comment: And also show us your full controller code

Comment: @user3546559 Can you share content of the `Cart` model in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You use an instance variable `@cart`, but I don't see where it's created. If it is, and you just omitted it in your snippet for simplicity sake, make sure your `Card` model has an association with `LineItem`:

```
has_many :line_items
```

Comment: My Cart model already have an association with LineItems. Thanks though!